# Backspace Not Working on VS Code's Bash Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

So, I'm new to VS code just installed it and I'm having an issue. The backspace doesn't work in the bash terminal of VS code. The backspace works on the cmd terminal of VS code though.

Not working means when I tap the backspace it prints a white space in the terminal.

Also the backspace key works perfectly fine on **Git Bash**

I tried googling but didn't find what I was looking for!

Please help.

Comment: Enter the following in terminal and check what happens: export TERM=xterm

Comment: Works for me on a bash integrated terminal in vscode.  Does it do anything?  Print some odd charachters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check your TERM by running `echo $TERM`, but before you do this I suggest you restart your vscode as you have already set the TERM by using the command. I think your TERM was set to something incompatible.

`export TERM=xterm` will set the emulator to xterm.

> Most application will expect that you already have the emulator set to something compatible such as xterm or linux.

For more information regarding what `export TERM=xterm` does you can check the following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/920915/977346)

Now, if you restart your vscode or terminal inside the vscode, `TERM` will reset to default and the problem will occur again. Therefore I suggest you add the `export TERM=xterm` in bash_profile or bashrc.

To add it to bashrc, type following in your terminal:

```
echo export TERM=xterm >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

go to command palette and select open shortcut key words go to this file and  delete all data in this file